# limiting choices shown in a the template

Tags: django

I have a list of time choices for booking a table in my model, when user want to book a table he will selec the time from the choices, but i want that as user select the time this time won't be shown again as available until the booking has been canceled or marked as "used".

My model...

```
class BookingTable(models.Model):
    
    TIME_CHOICES =[
        (time(8,0), '08:00'),
        (time(9,0), '09:00'),
        (time(10,0), '10:00'),
        (time(11,0), '11:00'),
        (time(12,0), '12:00'),
        (time(13,0), '13:00'),
        (time(14,0), '14:00'),
        (time(15,0), '15:00'),
        (time(16,0), '16:00'),
        (time(17,0), '17:00'),
        (time(18,0), '18:00'),
        (time(19,0), '19:00'),
        (time(20,0), '20:00'),
        (time(21,0), '21:00'),
    ]
     
    table = models.ForeignKey(Table, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.OneToOneField(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    time = models.TimeField(default='00:00', choices=TIME_CHOICES)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("list_tables")
       
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.user.username + "-" + self.table.name
    
    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['table', 'time'], name='table_time')
        ]
```

The view for booking table

```
class BookTableView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = BookingTable
    template_name = 'book_table.html'
    fields = ['time']
    context_object_name = 'booking'
    
    
    def form_valid(self, form):
        user_bookings = BookingTable.objects.filter(user_id=self.request.user.id)    
        if len(user_bookings) == 0:
            form.instance.user = self.request.user
            table = self.get_object(Table.objects)
            table.save()
            form.instance.table = table
            return super().form_valid(form)
        else:
            return render(self.request, 'booking_fail.html')
```

Comment: in the answer those TIME_CHOICES that are in the database are excluded from display. Can try to process canceled or marked as "used", but I don't understand how you identify them and what model fields are these?